# Change Double Fields to numeric

Tags: sql

> Possible duplicate of
>   [Alter every double fields of a table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6431564/alter-every-double-fields-of-a-table)

I need to change every double precision field of a table to numeric(15,3) type, how can i do this job quickly with a stored procedure that iterate through the field of a given table and if the type is double precision alter column to numeric ?

Answer (score 0):

i'd consider writing a few alter statements.

e.g.

```
alter table foo change myfield myfield numeric(30,6);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Query the Data Dictionary and generate the script. It would be better if you look at the script once and then run it instead of running the generated commands directly in a Procedure.

Eg. In Oracle, to convert say..number(2)to number(6), you can use a query like this..

```
create table test1(
  id number(2),
  name varchar2(50),
  count1 number(2)
)
/

select 'Alter Table ' || table_name || 
       ' modify ( ' || COLUMN_NAME || ' NUMBER(6)); '
  from user_tab_cols
  where table_name = 'TEST1'
    and data_type = 'NUMBER'
    and data_precision = 2
    and data_scale = 0
```

Output :

```
Alter Table TEST1 modify ( ID NUMBER(6)); 
Alter Table TEST1 modify ( COUNT1 NUMBER(6));
```

Review before you run it...